# Баг с выводом даты в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии кнопки должно выбивать дату в консоль, но в итоге дата выбивается при переходе на эту страницу и при выборе даты в пикере. При нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит. В чём моя ошибка?

```
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <div>
        <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}/>
        <button onClick={console.log(startDate)}>Hello</button>
    </div>

  );
```